# uploading video to youtube using nextjs and next-auth authorization

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to upload video to Youtube. I use Next-auth for Google OAuth authorization, but I have no idea how to implement video uploading functionality, can someone help me or give me some example?

Basically I'm trying to clone TunesToTube, where after signing in with your Google account, it lets you choose your Youtube channel (which don't work for me even though I tried many things, and searched entire google)

route.ts

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";



export const authOptions: any = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? "",
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? "",
    }),
  ],
  authorization: {
    params: {
      scope: [
        "openid",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
      ].join(" "),
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

export const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Answer (score 0):

change the scope array to this

```
scope: [
        "openid",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
      ].join(" "),
```

also you may need to refresh the access token whenever it expire so your next auth file should look somthing like this

```
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import User from "@/app/(models)/User";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export const options = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      profile(profile) {
        console.log("Profile GitHub: ", profile);

        let userRole = "GitHub User";
        if (profile?.email == "test@admin.com") {
          userRole = "admin";
        }

        return {
          ...profile,
          role: userRole,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_Secret,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      profile(profile) {
        console.log("Profile Google: ", profile);

        let userRole = "Google User";
        return {
          ...profile,
          id: profile.sub,
          role: userRole,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_Secret,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: [
            "openid",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
          ].join(" "),
        },
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "email:",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "your-email",
        },
        password: {
          label: "password:",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "your-password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email })
            .lean()
            .exec();

          if (foundUser) {
            console.log("User Exists");
            const match = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              foundUser.password
            );

            if (match) {
              console.log("Good Pass");
              delete foundUser.password;

              foundUser["role"] = "Unverified Email";
              return foundUser;
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        // Save the access token and refresh token in the JWT on the initial login
        console.log(account)
        return {
          access_token: account.access_token,
          expires_at: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + account.expires_in),
          refresh_token: account.refresh_token,
        }
      } else if (Date.now() < token.expires_at * 1000) {
        // If the access token has not expired yet, return it
        return token
      } else {
        // If the access token has expired, try to refresh it
        try {
          // https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
          // We need the `token_endpoint`.
          const response = await fetch("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            body: new URLSearchParams({
              client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
              client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
              grant_type: "refresh_token",
              refresh_token: token.refresh_token,
            }),
            method: "POST",
          })

          const tokens  = await response.json()

          if (!response.ok) throw tokens
          console.log(tokens.access_token)
          return {
            ...token, // Keep the previous token properties
            access_token: tokens.access_token,
            expires_at: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + tokens.expires_in),
            // Fall back to old refresh token, but note that
            // many providers may only allow using a refresh token once.
            refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token ?? token.refresh_token,
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error refreshing access token", error)
          // The error property will be used client-side to handle the refresh token error
          return { ...token, error: "RefreshAccessTokenError" }
        }
      }
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (session?.user) session.user.role = token.role;
      console.log(token.access_token)
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
      session.access_token = token.access_token
      session.user.id = token.id
      return session
    }
  },
};
```

dont forget to add the scope to in google dev console otherwise you will get ***Insufficient Permission*** error